# Facebook Login in Android application using Graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anybody has working sample code for Facebook login in Android using the code snippet mentioned in Facebook developer site ??I couldn't understand it properly.I want to get the name and profile picture of logged in user.I want my app to display the name and profile picture as long as the session is active and need to modify the details if user changed any.
Currently what i do is,saving access token and name in shared preferences on first login and saving the image in sd card and checking access token value during each app launch.If access token value is not null,then i display the name from shared preferences and profile picture from sd card.I know that this is not the right way to do this.Somebody please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can this https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook library it is pretty well defined and can get details of methods by searching simle facebook android on google. Do whatever you want to do with facebook with this library....happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Let me try this :)

Answer (score -1):

### Try this code

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private Button butLogin, butMaps, butJackpot, butAdministrator, buttonMenu;
public static String APP_ID = " paste your app_id";
public static Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
public static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private static final String TAG = "Activity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginToFacebook();
}           
// Method to call the Facebook login
protected void loginToFacebook() {
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("faceBook", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "public_profile",
                "publish_stream" }, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        getProfileInformation();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        getProfileInformation();
    }
}

// FaceBook getting profile information
public void getProfileInformation() {
    showLoadingImage();
    Helper.setFacebookLogin(getApplicationContext(), true);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            String json = response;
            try {
                Log.i("JSOB", json);
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                try {
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                    URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"
                            + profile.getString("id")
                            + "/picture?type=large");
                    bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String first_name= profile.getString("first_name"));
                String last_name=profile.getString("last_name"));
                String email=profile.getString("email"));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
   }

    // faceBook login method end

  }
```